# Getting error in KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.AzureBlobStorage.AzureBlobStorageServiceException in Azure Blob Storage Destination

Tags: azure, kingswaysoft

Trying to upload  a file from Flat File Source to Azure Blob storage using Azure Blob Storage destination using KingswaySoft Integration tool kit.

Steps followed:

1. Created Azure Storage connection which is working fine
2. But the task is giving error when executed

The full error details are:
[Azure Blob Storage Destination [2]] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.AzureBlobStorage.AzureBlobStorageServiceException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s (SSIS Productivity Pack, v23.1.0.7601 - DtsDebugHost, v15.0.2000.281)System.ArgumentNullException

: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s".

That file will be uploaded to Storage Container